# Google Cloud Storage can't retrieve buckets or contents of buckets

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

As of this morning I am unable to access my storage buckets.

When I select the Google Cloud Storage tab on the navigation everything loads as expected, but rather than displaying my two buckets it displays a alert bar saying:

> We were unable to retrieve your buckets. Click to Retry

As I'm aware of the link in to my bucket, i tried clicking on this and again, the page loads successfully, but I receive a new error message stating:

> Unable to retrieve objects. Click to Retry

This is true for both of my buckets.

Has anyone experienced and resolved this problem before?

EDIT: I can interface with the objects in the buckets using both the API and load them through browsers

Comment: I'm also seeing this starting within the last couple hours. I can't find a bugbase or official way to report issues for Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: I believe this should be fixed as of a few hours ago. Are you still seeing these errors?

For the record, bug reports and feature requests can be sent to gs-team@google.com, as is mentioned in our docs: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/resources-support

Comment: Thank you guys for getting back to me - It's all working now. And I missed the bug report, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote [@zach-wilt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2067359/zach-wilt): "I believe this should be fixed as of a few hours ago. Are you still seeing these errors? For the record, bug reports and feature requests can be sent to gs-team@google.com, as is mentioned in our docs: developers.google.com/storage/docs/resources-support"